# Pythonanywhereを使ってwebスクレイピングをしていたところ、エラーが出た

Tags: python, webapi

#### 解決したいこと

Pythonを使って、Pythonanywhereというサーバーを使ってwebスクレイピングで天気予報を
LINEに伝えるプログラムを作っています。
解決方法を教えてください。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/bin/pythonanywhere_runner.py", line 30, in _pa_run
    exec(code, new_variables)
  File "/home/ayasaka/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    res = requests.get(Request_URL_weather + '/city/' + City_ID)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/bin/pythonanywhere_runner.py", line 30, in _pa_run
    exec(code, new_variables)
  File "/home/ayasaka/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    res = requests.get(Request_URL_weather + '/city/' + City_ID)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
```

#### 該当するソースコード

```
import requests as requests
import schedule

Request_URL_weather = 'https://weather.tsukumijima.net/api/forecast'
Request_URL_LINE = 'https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify'

City_ID = '110020'
Token = 'APIキーが入っています。'

res = requests.get(Request_URL_weather + '/city/' + City_ID)
```

#### 自分で試したこと

ローカル環境でソースコードの実行してみたところ、うまくいきました。

Comment: Pythonanywhere側の問題（スクリプトを直接実行しているが、 `requests` を使って外部サーバに通信する箇所で問題が起きている）に見えます。 通信先のサイトは[Pythonanywhereからも接続可能](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/)なので、原因はPythonanywhere内にありそうです。一度他のホスティングサービスを試してみてはいかがでしょうか？